# Unable to iterate through a list -pyPDF2

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pypdf

Running below code is throwing error at line `pdfReader`

```
pdf=['/somepath/a.pdf','/somepath/b.pdf']

for count in range(len(pdf)):
    name=pdf[count]
    pdfFileObj = open(name, 'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj) #Error at this line
    pages=pdfReader.numPages
```

Error- PdfReadWarning: Xref table not zero-indexed. ID numbers for objects will be corrected. [pdf.py:1736]

However when I am just passing pdf location below like this its working , but I need a loop so that every pdf can be used..

```
pdfFileObj = open(pdf[0], 'rb')
```

Even I tried look like , but it again failing at `PdfReader`

```
for p in pdf:
    pdfFileObj = open(p, 'rb')
```

Comment: The second form of your loop is much more pythonic

Comment: The fact that index zero works just means that it fails on the second file

Comment: Thanks@MadPhysicist .So, if strict=False will be passed it will be Fixed , correct ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this site](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/36), this error means that the first section of the xref table does not begin with object zero. You can overcome this by passing the option `strict = false` and PyPDF2 will automatically correct the object ID numbers. Usually this is not a big problem and Adobe will still read your PDF's. Cheers.